# Triangle javascript problem/ Unit testing not working (Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I written code to determine if a triangle is equilateral, isosceles, or scalene. Next, I'm suppose to test it using Jasmine but my code keep failing. I am very new to unit testing. Please help me!

TriangleSpec:

```
describe('Determine if a triangle is equilateral, isolene, scalene', 
function () {
  it('equilateral triangles have equal sides', function () {
    var triangle = new isTriangle (5, 5, 5)
    expect(triangle).toEqual("Equilateral");
  });
```

Triangle.js:

```
function isTriangle(side1, side2, side3){
  if (side1 === 0 || side2 === 0 || side3 === 0) {
      console.log("Error");
  } else if (side1 < 0 || side2 < 0 || side3 < 0) {
      console.log("Error");
  } else if (side1 + side2 <= side3 || side1 + side3 <= side2 || side2 +
    side3 <= side1) {
    console.log("Error");
  }
  else if (side1 == side2 && side2 == side3) {
    console.log("Equilateral");
  } else if (side1 === side2 || side2 === side3 || side1 === side3) {
    console.log("Isosceles");
  } else {
    console.log("Scalene");
  }
};

isTriangle(6, 6, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- Your `isTriangle` function is not *returning* the result; it merely outputs it with `console.log`, but that does not count as the return value of a function. So replace all your `console.log("some result")` to `return "some result"`
- The function is not a constructor, so it should not be called with `new`. In your test code just do: `var triangle = isTriangle (5, 5, 5)`